# How to make a repeatedly scrolling background cocos2d (iPhone)?

Tags: iphone, background, cocos2d-iphone

I'm extremely new to cocos2D development and I have hit a problem with my background. I want it to repeat scrolling every 2000px so I have looked around and found this (in this [tutorial](http://www.raywenderlich.com/3611/how-to-make-a-space-shooter-iphone-game)):

```
[_backgroundNode incrementOffset:ccp(2000,0) forChild:background];
```

I have set this up in my program however it doesn't recognise the method 'incrementOffset'. Is there something I'm doing wrong? I have imported `"CCParallaxNode.h"`, however it says I need to import `"CCParallaxNode-Extras.h"` which doesn't exist?!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To quote the tutorial:

> I’ve created a category on CCParallaxNode that you can use to solve
>   this problem, which you can find in the [resources for this project](http://d1xzuxjlafny7l.cloudfront.net/downloads/SpaceGameResources.zip) in
>   the Classes folder. Drag CCParallaxNode-Extras.h and
>   CCParallaxNode-Extras.m into your project, make sure “Copy items into
>   destination group’s folder” is checked, and click Finish.